# Why confirm purchase using postback URL?

Tags: android-pay

[Google Wallet docs](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial) (for digital goods) say:

> Note: These callback handlers are not secure. Someone could use
>   Firebug or the Chrome Developer Tools to call one of the functions,
>   mocking a success or failure. **You should confirm the purchase [on the
>   server](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial#5)**.

<sub>The link in the quote being to specifying a postback URL.</sub>

But since the jwt is signed by Google - why is that needed? We can simply check the signature of the **success handler**'s jwt in the page's codebehind on the server.

<sub>(And if signing isn't enough - it shouldn't be enough at the postback url either, because if someone discovers the url - they might send a POST there and the problem returns.)</sub>

Answer (score 7):

1. The purpose of the callback url is to let you know that a purchase has been made
2. You verify the posted data before you actually "consume" the data, it shouldn't matter if  your postback url is "discovered" in the wild.
3. You tell Google that you were able to **successfully** record said order in your systems and that you can "fulfill" said order. Otherwise, if for any reason your end wasn't able to record/process/etc the order, meaning you won't "fulfill it", then the user (buyer) has to know as well.

### I haven't tested this (I use postback url)

The documentation states **[**IF** you specify a postback url](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/postback)** . So you can try not providing one and process the way you describe above (which is still "server side").

### Possible issue

Assuming your test works, the difference between the two:

- in the scenario **with** the postback url, all parties concerned, buyer, you and Google are "in sync" - if you can't fulfill for whatever reason, have some server issue on your end, etc., then the transaction fails (no order generated) for **all**.
- in the scenario **without** the postback url, assuming a success, the transaction *may* have different states:

  - Google : Good, recorded, in buyer's Wallet transactions list
  - Your systems : possibly good, or not, or not even recorded

    - based on however your page processes the data *at that time*
    - any script error on the client/browser, or any other reason coming from the client side that may prevent your page from processing
  - User/buyer - has order in his/her Wallet transactions - "success" as far as Google is concerned

Hope this helps...

### Update:

There is another "benefit" (could be critical in some flows) where security is concerned. With a postback url, you obtain the order details for yet-another-verification step (e.g. based on order-id). You can verify whether an order sent by/from client is "valid" (whatever business rule - e.g. `if order-id exists then.....`) because the success callback happens **after** the postback.

e.g. mock by replaying the *same (valid) JWT* (within bounds of iat/any expiration)

There could be myriad flows that sellers/devs come up with in their app so using "postback url verification processes" mitigates possible issues.

Hth....

Comment: a) Thanks. b) I did not mean to question the benefits of a postback url (Though I now see that my question was worded that way). I _am_ questioning the quote that implies that it _must_ be used to avoid a fake success.

Comment: My understanding of your answer is that if the success handler's jwt's signature is checked in the codebehind - it is indeed secure (though, it might be the wrong way to go about things for other reasons, as you have pointed out.) I hope I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I use postbacks to deliver the goods (in our case e-tickets).  I have implemented the wallet postback and this gives me various parameters such as google's user_id.

I do not see how I can determine who the user is so, without this, I cannot send them the digital good.  Is there some way I can get this?

On other systems I used to provide an order ID that went into the pay button and came out through the callback.  I do not see such an input in the wallet code examples or tutorials.

Thx Paul

Note: I later guessed the answer, tested it and provided it here: [how to get user information in google wallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149873/how-to-get-user-information-in-google-wallet/18546347#18546347)

Answer (score -1):

Like the docs say, all client side code can be easily changed using various browser dev tools and therefore should not be trusted.

I think what they are concerned with is that the javascript could be manipulated so that your server thinks that a payment has taken place, and the user gets a product that they did not actually pay for.

If someone discovers the URL and posts to it, they have no control over the server code, so the server will take payment from their card so its not really a problem.

Comment: Thanks. But my server will check the success handler's jwt's signature. And since manipulating the JavaScript won't manipulate the page's codebehind on the server - that is not a problem.

Comment: @ispiro if your server is checking the jwt's signature, then you are doing EXACTLY what google tells you to do. If you do it from client's side (i.e., have a javascript call your server with the jwt data), the source of the jwt is unknown and could be mocked by a javascript injected script... if you do it from the postback URL, you are sure it comes from Google (and you acknowledge it to Google too).

Comment: @Jcl `then you are doing EXACTLY what google tells you to do` - No. That's why I wrote (albeit in small text): `The link in the quote being to specifying a postback URL.`

Comment: Yes, that's what I explained afterwards... if the JWT that comes to your server comes from a client-side script, it can be mocked... if it comes from a postback URL from Google, it cannot (or... not that easily)

Comment: @jcl - The signature **cannot** be mocked. That's precisely the point of the signature. (And see my last comment in the question.)